# want to use plus minus icon at foreach loop at collapse expend using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

Below i have a foreach loop, there i use icon plus class. After click my javascript function myFunction(); i want to add minus icon.

```
$i=0; $j=0; $k=0; $l=0;
foreach ($cat_group_head_first as $ccgrouphead) {
?>
<span class="acc-trigger" style="width: 100% !important;">
   <a onclick="myFunction('#cat_head<?php echo $i=$i+1;?>');">
   <b>{{$ccgrouphead->GroupHead}} 
    
      <!-- want to use plus minus icon below icon class-->
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
   </b>
   </a>
</span>
<?php
}
```

Comment: `Below i have a foreach loop` no you don't. `i want to add minus icon` as a guess. that could be `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>`

Comment: I want to add the minus icon at the place of plus icon, after click the at myFunction(); Default display plus icon.

Comment: The below code, take same icon for all the foreach loop item.  $('.acc-trigger').addClass('acc-trigger active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 $('acc-trigger').addClass('acc-trigger active');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my question solution:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('.acc-trigger').click(function() { // when a .myDiv is clicked

  $(this).toggleClass('active')
  })
</script>
```

css:

.acc-trigger{
background: url(https://bdtender.com/images/accordion-plus.png) no-repeat right 50%;
}
.acc-trigger.active{
background: url(https://bdtender.com/images/accordion-minus.png) no-repeat right 50%;
}